How to disable the link to the third dimension of a parallel categories graph in plotly?
I have a dataframe like this
  source     target mortality  count   color
0    VSD        VSD       Yes     65     red
1    VSD       CABG       Yes     43    blue
2    VSD       Ross        No     31  yallow
3    VSD  Freestyle        No     56  purple

I created a snakey diagram using the plotly's parallel categories. This is the cordiagram I created

Note: The data displayed in the graph is different from the data in the dataframe above.
I want to remove the "No" category in the third category from the graph and the link goes from the second dimension to the third dimension.
Any Ideas?
this the code I wrote to create the graph
fig = go.Figure(
        go.Parcats(
            dimensions=[
                {"label": options["procedure"], "values": final_df["Isolated"]},
                {"label": "", "values": final_df["Combined"]},
                {"label": "Mortality", "values": final_df["Mortality"]},
            ],
            counts=final_df["count"],
            line={"shape": "hspline", "color": final_df["color"]},
            arrangement="freeform",
        )
    )

I tried to set the white color to the data labelled by "No" but it ends up the link from the first to the third dimension is colored white. I just need the part from the second to the third dimension. I tried also to set the count of data labelled by "No" as 0 but this doesn't work also.

You can filter the data. Here is what happens if you do nothing:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {
    "source": ["VSD", "VSD", "VSD", "VSD"],
    "target": ["VSD", "CABG", "Ross", "Freestyle"],
    "mortality": ["Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"],
    "count": [65, 43, 31, 56],
    "color": ["red", "blue", "yellow", "purple"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

filtered_df = df
#filtered_df = df[df["mortality"] == "Yes"]

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Parcats(
        dimensions=[
            {"label": "Source", "values": filtered_df["source"]},
            {"label": "Target", "values": filtered_df["target"]},
            {"label": "Mortality", "values": filtered_df["mortality"]},
        ],
        counts=filtered_df["count"],
        line={"shape": "hspline", "color": filtered_df["color"]},
        arrangement="freeform",
    )
)

fig.show()

which gives

and here is what happens if you change
filtered_df = df

to
filtered_df = df[df["mortality"] == "Yes"]


Update: From comment:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {
    "source": ["VSD", "VSD", "VSD", "VSD"],
    "target": ["VSD", "CABG", "Ross", "Freestyle"],
    "mortality": ["Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"],
    "count": [65, 43, 31, 56],
    "color": ["red", "blue", "yellow", "purple"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

filtered_df = df

filtered_df["color"] = filtered_df.apply(lambda row: row["color"] if row["mortality"] == "Yes" else "rgba(0,0,0,0)", axis=1)

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Parcats(
        dimensions=[
            {"label": "Source", "values": filtered_df["source"]},
            {"label": "Target", "values": filtered_df["target"]},
            {"label": "Mortality", "values": filtered_df["mortality"]},
        ],
        counts=filtered_df["count"],
        line={"shape": "hspline", "color": filtered_df["color"]},
        arrangement="freeform",
    )
)

fig.show()


which gives:


Correct if we want to show the Yes mortality label. I want to have Yes and No but disable the colours of No from the Target dimension to the Mortality dimension so that the end user can see that a small proportion of the patients died and the rest of them survived successfully.

@NemraKhalil Updated my answer to what I think you meant in you comment. Let me know if it is what you expected.

Thanks for your great help. I did it with go.Sankey(). Find the answer below

Due to some difficulties in doing it with go.Parcats(). I did it with go.Sankey() instead. Here is the full code:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {
    "source": ["VSD", "VSD", "VSD", "VSD", "VSD"],
    "target": ["Isolated", "Isolated", "CABG", "Ross", "Freestyle"],
    "mortality": ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"],
    "count": [65, 39, 43, 31, 56],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
total_df = df.groupby(["source", "target"])["count"].sum().reset_index()
mortality_df = df[df["mortality"] == "Yes"]

unique_procedures = list(pd.unique(total_df["target"])) 
all_procedures = list(pd.unique(total_df["source"])) + unique_procedures + ["Mortality"]

node_indcies = {node: index for index, node in enumerate(all_procedures)}

# create source, target, value lists for firt flow
source = [node_indcies[list(pd.unique(total_df["source"]))[0]]] * len(total_df)
target = [node_indcies[procedure] for procedure in total_df["target"]]
values = total_df["count"].to_list()

# create source, target, value lists for second flow
source += [node_indcies[procedure] for procedure in mortality_df["target"]]
target += [node_indcies["Mortality"]] * len(mortality_df)
values += mortality_df["count"].to_list()

# Create the Sankey diagram
fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    node=dict(
        pad=15,
        thickness=20,
        line=dict(color="black", width=0.5),
        label=all_procedures,
        align="center"
    ),
    link=dict(
        source=source,
        target=target,
        value=values,
        color=['blue']*len(total_df) + ['red']*len(mortality_df)  # Optional: color links for better visualization
    )
))

fig.update_layout(title_text="VSD Outcome", font_size=10)

fig.update_traces({"textfont": {"weight": "bold"}})
fig.show()


